# Expression to validate Password in Oracle ADF using af:validateRegExp

Tags: java, regex, oracle-adf

I would like to validate a inputtext for password validation:

Atleast one number
Atleast one special character
Atleast one uppercase letter 
Minimum 8 characters

Does anyone know how I can declare a string with the expression for the above. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this in ADF Faces is to drag an af:validateRegExp component onto the inputTextField. Find this in the component palette under Operations > Validators and Converters. Then use the Property window to configure the pattern, etc.

Comment: yes, I am using validateRegExp. My question is about the pattern. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: it uses java regular expression. there are many places on the web to learn how to write reg expressions.